# CALayer is not type-casted to CATiledLayer

Tags: xcode, catiledlayer

I am new to iPhone programming. I want to use CATiledLayer to load an image.
I am creating the subclass of UIVIew class and in the init method of that class, I am writing,

```
      CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];
```

But when I am writing

```
      tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 4;
```

It gives me the error that 
    [CALayer setLevelsOfDetail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcd04450

So to check the class-type of tiledLayer,I am writing following statements :

```
NSString *pqr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", [tiledLayer class]];
NSLog(pqr);
```

But it prints CALayer instead of CATiledLayer. Why is it so?? What am I missing??
Now I am stuck here. :(

Answer (score 1):

Applying a typecast to a pointer in Objective-C has no effect at runtime (it does have some effect during compile time, so this syntax is still used at times).

So, your "typecast" is not actually doing a typecast. It's just informing the compiler (in that one line of code only) that this is a `CATiledLayer` and not a `CALayer` as it has been declared. The actual object is really still a `CATiledLayer`.

In order to change the class of `self.layer`, you define a static method to return the class:

```
@implementation MyView

+ (Class)layerClass
{
  return [CATiledLayer class];
}

@end
```

And now, when the layer for any `MyView` instance is created, it will be a `CATiledLayer` instead of a `CALayer`.